# What could cause a toilet to bubble occasionally, even if sewer line is clear?

Tags: toilet

I've had a problem for the last month with my toilet emitting air bubbles when I shower. I've had sewer blockage before due to tree roots, so I thought this might be the cause. I had the line snaked out to the street and then back through the house, but it still didn't seem to help. We then tried to snake through the actual toilet bowl, and that helped a bit, but the plumber said that it may be mineral deposits and that I would probably need a new toilet.

In the meantime, we haven't been using that toilet, but this morning it started bubbling again when I showered. I've never heard of mineral deposits in the actual toilet causing this. Has anyone else? I just want to make sure before I go to the trouble of replacing the toilet.

Comment: Sounds like the vent stack is plugged

Comment: Do you have any flat spots or negative slope in the drain lines between the toilet and the shower?

Comment: maplemale - not sure about the slope, I'll have to check that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak That could be turned into an answer. I know what you're getting at, but you were here first.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk you can go ahead

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how clear the drain lines are, if you have blocked, obstructed or inappropriately sized plumbing vent stacks, the bubbles could be emanating because the air being displaced as the drain line fills from the shower, have no easier path of resistance than your toilet.

TL:DR You've cleaned and investigated downstream, maybe it's time to look upstream.